# Is rate of effusion directly proportional to pressure

Tags: gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases, ideal-gas

From [Graham's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_law) of effusion we know that rate of effusion is inversely proportional to square root of density of gas but if two gases are being effused at different pressures then is rate directly proportional to pressure?

Comment: Yes, it is proportional for ideal gases. For real gases, there are deviations for high pressures.